# My kivy project keeps crashing on my computer

Tags: crash, kivy

I am unable to test my kivy in python

I was expecting the app to work just fine

but i it is not running wasting my valuable time and i am not able to code if anybody has an answer please let me know thank you.

Comment: No person can answer your question without seeing your code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please send your code we cant do anything for you until you do